# Why nested subscription is not good?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know that nested subscriptions should be avoided and rxjs operators should be used, but the articles I found about this issue usually just saying that nested subscriptions is bad without explaining why(besides saying 'may cause issues') .

I'm wondering if anyone can help on this one? Thank you.

Comment: rxjs was designed so that you can combine several operators into one observable that can be subscribed to.  It was designed to be flexible that way.  You can create complex behaviors by combining several rxjs operators together.  By creating multiple subscriptions (and multiple observables), while that might work, you are going against how the library was intended to be used.

Comment: Most importantly it makes the inner subscriptions unsubscribable.

Comment: Consider one user-case, where you are getting Two API data back. First call of API is input for Second API get. and you do not know time consumed by both API or which one completes first. In this scenario rxJS Operator is used for such task to complete. You can use several operator for that ..

Comment: nest subscription is more like the callback hell from the past day.

Comment: Because you are not setting up a single observable chain. Use switchMap and you only have to manage a single subscription rather than multiple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good that you are asking since this is a common problem.

Consider something like

```
service.cal1().subscribe(val => {
  service.call2(val).subscribe( res => {
    *does things*
  }
}
```

What you are triggering is a new Subscription (and therefor a new executed pipe) for each an every value that get emited by the Observable of `call1()`. 
This can leave you with hundreds of unhandled Observables ans Subscriptions which all stay in memory for the time being.

You need to know that when you `subscribe()` to a Observable multiple times, your subscribers won't listen to the exact same source, instead they all trigger a new copy of your defined Observable pipeline.

As stated in the first example in the [Observable Docu](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

> Observable that pushes the values 1, 2, 3 immediately (synchronously) **when subscribed**

*Emphasize mine*

The Observable does nothing on its own but starts its whole journey **whenever subscribed**

That is why you would try to use something like [switchMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) to change to the other call instead of leaving the original subscription as is.

Answer (score 5):

```
let sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4;
sub1 = service.call1().subscribe(result1 => {
  sub2 = service.call2(result1).subscribe(result2 => {
    sub3 = service.call3(result2).subscribe(result3 => {
      sub4 = service.call4(result3).subscribe(result4 => {
        // Do stuff with result 4
      });
    });
  });
});
```

vs

```
let sub = service.call1().pipe(
  switchMap(result1 => service.call2(result1)),
  switchMap(result2 => service.call3(result2)),
  switchMap(result3 => service.call4(result3)),
  switchMap(result4 => service.call5(result4))
)
```