# Not load data onClose dialog ? using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to trigger load data ( which also load on init ) when user close dialog.

in AddUser-component.ts i have any logic and only important part

```
  public onClose: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


  this.addService.addNewUser(user).subscribe(res => {
   this.onClose.next(res.body)
   this.bsModalRef.hide();
 }
```

and when trigger this in main component AllUser-components.ts i have

```
public addNewUser() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AddUserComponent); 
    (this.bsModalRef.content as AddUserComponent).onClose.subscribe(singleUserFromChildComponent)=>{
        this.loadUser(); // HERE IS PROBLEM... when i console.log this.allUsers i don't see new added user .....
        if (bill) {
            this.lastAddedItem(this.allUsers, singleUserFromChildComponent);  
        }
        this.bsModalRef.hide()
    })
}
```

and above i have loadUser

```
private loadUser() {
    this.service.getAllUsers( 
    ).subscribe((res) => {
        this.allUsers = res.body!; 
    })
}
```

this.allUsers var is not updated....not load new user.... why ? I load data and allUsers need to be updated with new data

```
 this.allUsers = res.body!;
```

but not... i don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Well its because the loadUser() method is asynchronous, and while you are loading it on modal close, it does not finish yet (also having nested subscriptions is a kind of bad practice, you can read more in that thread [Why nested subscription is not good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797081/why-nested-subscription-is-not-good))

What I can suggest you is to remove the subscribe invocation from loadUser method and return just an observable:

```
  private loadUser() {
    return this.service.getAllUsers().pipe(map((res: any) => res.body!),tap((res: any) => this.allUsers = res));
}
```

In your OnInit (or constructor method initialize allUsers in this way.

```
this.loadUser().pipe(first()).subscribe();
```

and then refactor your modal close part with the switchMap( it will wait untill your  service.getAllUsers finished)

```
public addNewUser() {
  this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AddUserComponent); 
    (this.bsModalRef.content as AddUserComponent).onClose
    .pipe(tap(singleUserFromChildComponent => this.singleUserFromChildComponent = singleUserFromChildComponent), switchMap(addedUser => (this.loadUser()))).subscribe(_ => {
      if (bill) {
        this.lastAddedItem(this.allUsers, this.singleUserFromChildComponent);  
    }
    this.bsModalRef.hide()
    });
}
```

also please add the lastAddedUser property to your component

```
public singleUserFromChildComponent: any;
```